# How to set c++ standard in clion (bazel project)?

Tags: c++, bazel

I've just started using bazel in clion (used to use cmake) and have faced with problem: I can compile the project via terminal using

```
bazel build --cxxopt="--std=c++17" :tests
```

but clion says that, for example, `auto` and `unique_ptr` (i.o. c++11 and higher features) are unknown. So how to make clion use c++14?

Comment: The question is about bazel, not cmake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is: you have to create '.bazelrc' in your project's root directory with folowing code:

```
build --cxxopt="--std=c++<version>"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also enter compiler version in the cc_binary of your BUILD.bazel.

```
cc_binary(
    name = "hello_world",
    srcs = ["hallo_world.cpp"],
    # hdrs = [""],
    deps = [
         "//projects/lib:greeter", 
         "//projects/lib2:greeter2"
    ],
    copts = ["-std=c++20"],  # Enter your C++ version here...
)
```